# Wso2 ESB and Bam: why operator name is always be "mediate"?

Tags: wso2, operator-keyword, esb, wso2-bam

I'm now using WSO2 ESB for creating WebService Proxy and Bam for monitoring. I can seee the data in Bam explorer, but the payload_operation_name is always be "mediate". 
How could I config to see the real name of the operation?

Comment: Do you have a WSDL attached to the proxy ?

Comment: Yes, I think I did. In proxy setting --> general setting --> publish wsdl, I set the wsdl link of WebService, then set parameter "disableValidateOperator = true" to unable to call service. I could see all operator in proxy, and in SoapUI, but strangely, it also make me  unable to see any statistic of proxy service after doing those settings.

Comment: Which ESB version are using ? 4.8 ? 4.9 ?

Comment: I'm using version 4.8. And I also try version 4.9. The results are the same :(

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I think you are using the Service Data Agent [1] to capture the proxy related statistics here where as you actually need to us the Mediation Data Agent for that. Because the Service Data Agent is mainly for statistics monitoring of the axis2 services, and hence you are getting the operation name as 'mediate' always when accessing the proxy service. The correct way to go forward is to use, Mediation Data Agent, but it will not publish the operation name what you are accessing, and if your backend services is axis2 service then you could use WSO2 Application server and use the Service Data Agent to collect the operation level stats of the web service. If your back end service is not within WSO2 servers, then you can use BAM mediator [3] or Publish Event Mediator (if ESB 4.9.0) [4] to publish this information to BAM.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/BAM250/Setting+up+Service+Statistics+Data+Agent

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/BAM250/Setting+up+Mediation+Stat+Data+Agent

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/BAM250/Setting+up+BAM+Mediator

[4] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Publish+Event+Mediator